# Getting probability density graph & k-means clustering with 300 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, mahout, nosql

The DBMS I use is MySQL(MariaDB).

The table scheme is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
ID     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
TEXT   VARCHAR(200),
VALUE  DECIMAL(15,2) )
```

The table has 300 million rows or more.

I'd like to get the result from the following two processes by extracting values from the texts(For example, `SELECT VALUE FROM MyTable WHEN TEXT LIKE '%any keywords%';` SQL) (Results to be displayed on the web)

1. To draw probability density graph
2. To cluster values by using K-Means Algorithm

Is it possible to obtain the results above only by using SQL? If so, how is the performance? (the required response time is less than 2 seconds) If not, could you recommend better way?

If there are 10 data nodes with the combination of `NoSQL` and `Mahout`, is it possible to get the result from each query within 2 seconds especially when there are 5 queries per second? If not, how many data nodes are required?

So, please recommand me the system architecture if you know any solution to the trouble I've currently run into.

Comment: Queries with `LIKE '%...'` can't use an index and will performance poorly. You may look into the [fulltext functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks @VMai . I just wanted to give you an example how I filter the records. It helped anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Your expectations are a bit extreme.  It would might be possible to meet the requirements, using a lot of custom code and systems with lots of processors and lots of memory.

First, you don't seem to understand how k-means works.  What is the distance metric?

Second, you don't explain why you need to re-cluster the records for each query.  Typically, clustering is more of an offline activity and scoring (or assigning clusters) is online.

Finally, I wouldn't recommend k-means clustering on raw text.  There are other algorithms for clustering text that could very well be more appropriate for your actual problem.  I would suggest you learn a bit about data mining (What is the k-means algorithm?  What is it useful?  What is expectation-maximization clustering?  What is singular value decomposition?)  I would also suggest that you learn about text analysis (What is tokenization?  What is stemming?  What are bag-of-words approaches?  What is semantic analysis?).  Your question betrays a lack of understanding of both these subjects.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
What I need to cluster is just using one parameter (Please refer 'VALUE' colomn above.)
As it has one demension, distance matric will be abs(value-value).
Probably, I made a mistake to deliver what I meant. I didn't mean that I'm going to cluster texts. just numeric values.

Comment: @KeithPark . . . Clustering along one dimension is often overkill.  It sounds like a reasonable solution would be to break the range into centiles and just do a histogram within each centile.  That can make a respectable picture too.

Comment: That is a great idea. That's one of reason why I asked that I want to get probability density graph. Data would be concentrated to 3~5 clusters. but the problem is that each cluster will be along norminal distribution. and can be overlapped.